# Laravel hasOne conditional relationship

Tags: php, laravel, orm, laravel-4

I have a User model and each user has a type of either internal or external. The data stored on internal and external users is very different so there are separate UserInternal and UserExternal models.

How can I define this relationship? There's a key 'user_id' in the UserInternal and UserExternal tables, and each user will have a matching row in one of the tables.

When I retrieve user data it's always via the User model, but I then want the extended data.

How would I go about doing it? I tried this, but it doesn't always work (for example if I try `User::with('data') -> find(1)` it won't work because $this won't be set yet.

Within User model:

```
public function data()
{
    if( $this -> type === 'internal' )
    {
        return $this -> hasOne('UserInternal');
    }
    else
    {
        return $this -> hasOne('UserExternal');
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try to load the relation after getting the user:

```
$user = User::find(1);

if( ! is_null($user))
{
    $user->load('data');
}
```

Comment: Yep - looks like this is going to have to be the way I go, just wondered if there would be a more advanced option!

Comment: @Ryu_hayabusa what methods are you referring to? If I'm not wrong, just relationship methods must be camelCase.

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can chain `find()` after anything else in an [Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent) model.

An alternative opposed to the other answer would be:

```
User::with('data')->where('user_id', 1)->first();
```

Comment: The chaining does work, but only if there's no conditional. So if it was always returning the first option it worked fine

Comment: Ah ok. Thanks, looked like you found your answer anyway :).